# String to Dictionary or Array in C#

Tags: c#, c, arrays, dictionary

I have a string as followed:

> Charlie Sheen is Cool
>  BBBB
>  He likes to run
>  BBB
>   When does he run?
>  BBBB
>
> He lives here
>  BBBB
>  ?
>  [
>  I like Charlie Sheen
>   BBBB

I would like to separate the string into two different Arrays. One for the phrases on top of the B's and for the B's itself. Or even better, have a dictionary with the phrases as the key's and the B's as values. I would also like to ignore all empty lines and lines that do not start with a letter. How would I go about doing it?

```
string[] newText = file.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n",},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int count = 0;
Regex symbol = new Regex("^[[]]$"); //these are the symbols I want to detect
Dictionary<string, string> patternedText = new Dictionary<string,string>();

foreach(string s in newText){
int bCount = 0;
count++;
bCount++; //position of where it detects a match
if(symbol.isMatch(s)){ 
newText[count-bCount] = s;
    }else{ newText[count] = s;
   patternedText.Add(newText[count],newText[count+1]);
}
```

Basically I want the format of the array to be:
Phrase with symbols
BBB
Phrase with symbols
BBBB
Phrase
BBB with symbols

And filter out all empty lines and the symbols on any line to be added to only the phrases.

Comment: Please provide some code! What you have tried so far?

Comment: I edited the post and explained a bit more! sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you can do:

1. split the string using '\n' (new line feed), that will give you
   an array of all lines.
2. Use a regular expression and/or a loop to do the cleaning (remove lines with only one symbol and the BBB in the succeeding line).
3. Create a dictionary  and
   iterate the array to put the (n)th element as the key and (n+1)th
   element as the value. (be careful of the boundary lines).

Comment: Is there a way to filter the string so that if there was an empty line, it wouldn't get added to the new split array?

Comment: try using StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries which is an argument of the string.split method.

Comment: Some lines only contain one symbol. Is there anyway to take the symbol from that line and move it to the previous line?

Comment: Do you want to remove the BBB.. in the line next to the symbol? I have updated the logic flow in the answer.

Comment: No, sorry. Lets say there was a symbol under the BBB line, how would I shift the array so that the symbol is concatenated to the previous "phrase" index and not BBB index, which would work for any symbol on any line

Comment: So you need to use the first loop (in my #2), use a regexp to check if its a one-character symbol, if so append it to the end of the (n-2)th position. But be careful when you delete elements from the existing array while iterating it, because  you will end up with a index-out-of-range error.

Answer (score 0):

A loop is the sane and efficient approach, but if you're a LINQaholic:

```
var dictionary = file.Split(new[] {"\r\n", "\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select((line, index) => (line, index))
    .GroupBy(tuple => tuple.index / 2)
    .ToDictionary(group => group.First().line, group => group.Last().line);
```

Comment: I am just starting out in C# and haven't used LINQ. Could you go over what it does?

Comment: `Select` pairs each line of text with its line number so that `GroupBy` can use the line number to group every even line with the subsequent odd line.  `ToDictionary` converts the sequence of groups to a dictionary, using the first line as the key and the second line as the value.  That's a quick-and-inadequate explanation, but after you learn the fundamental concepts that comprise LINQ, it should become more clear.

Comment: @bautk16 The `System.Linq` namespace has many nifty things in it, including some `IEnumerable<T>` extensions. The three mentioned in this answer work as follows: `Select` applies a function to each item in an enumerable and returns the transformed enumerable. `GroupBy` groups the elements of an enumerable into "buckets" according to the key selector that you apply, so items that have the same result from the key selector go into the same bucket. `ToDictionary` is kind of like `Select`, but gives you a dictionary with keys generated from the first function and values generated from the second.